# IOS app is crashing on IOS 7.1 but works with IOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios7.1

I have an app that is live on the app store, but it isn't launching on IOS 7.1 devices. I set the deployment target for IOS 7.1, but my base sdk is IOS 8. It makes sense that this would case a crash on non-ios8 devices. Am I correct in my thinking? Do I need to go back and use the IOS 7.1 SDK??

Comment: Update your question with the stack trace from the crash report and the full and complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using iOS 8. But you need to check in your code where you are using iOS 8 only API calls and exclude them from running on iOS 7. If you are not sure what to do, then change the deployment target to iOS 8.